# Compiling SWAN on Mac with M2 chip using GFortran

Tags: c, compiler-errors, apple-m1, gfortran

I am following the instructions for compiling SWAN [here](https://swanmodel.sourceforge.io/download/zip/swanimp.pdf) in Section 3.2.2, downloaded from [here](https://swanmodel.sourceforge.io/download/download.htm) on an Apple MacOS with an M2 chip. After downloading and unpacking the tarball, I cd to the swan directory and enter

```
make config
make ser
```

as instructed, and get a series of errors which I will include at the end of the post. I'm not familiar with compilation of Fortran and am doing this very much against my will.

It looks (to my untrained eye) like the compiler is using a slightly different version of Fortran because it seems like it is finding syntax errors in the code.

```
<...> % which gfortran
/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran
```

Is this an issue with GFortran, or with the M2 chip? Sorry if this has already been posted, I checked but didn't understand any of the answers for my case.

```
make FOR=gfortran FFLAGS="-O -w -fno-second-underscore " \
            FFLAGS90="-O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none " \
                INCS="" LIBS="" OBJS="swmod1.o swmod2.o SwanSpectPart.o m_constants.o m_fileio.o serv_xnl4v5.o mod_xnl4v5.o SwanGriddata.o SwanGridobjects.o SwanCompdata.o SdsBabanin.o SwanIEM.o SwanBraggScat.o SwanQCM.o  swan2coh.o swanmain.o swanpre1.o swanpre2.o swancom1.o swancom2.o swancom3.o swancom4.o swancom5.o swanout1.o swanout2.o swanser.o swanparll.o SwanReadGrid.o SwanReadADCGrid.o SwanReadTriangleGrid.o SwanReadEasymeshGrid.o SwanInitCompGrid.o SwanCheckGrid.o SwanCreateEdges.o SwanGridTopology.o SwanGridVert.o SwanGridCell.o SwanGridFace.o SwanPrintGridInfo.o SwanFindPoint.o SwanPointinMesh.o SwanBpntlist.o SwanPrepComp.o SwanVertlist.o SwanCompUnstruc.o SwanDispParm.o SwanPropvelX.o SwanSweepSel.o SwanPropvelS.o SwanTranspAc.o SwanTranspX.o SwanDiffPar.o SwanGSECorr.o SwanGradDepthorK.o SwanGradVel.o SwanInterpolatePoint.o SwanInterpolateAc.o SwanInterpolateOutput.o SwanConvAccur.o SwanConvStopc.o SwanThreadBounds.o SwanFindObstacles.o SwanCrossObstacle.o SwanComputeForce.o SwanIntgratSpc.o SwanBndStruc.o SwanReadfort18.o SwanPunCollect.o SwanSumOverNodes.o SwanMinOverNodes.o SwanMaxOverNodes.o SwanVTKWriteHeader.o SwanVTKWriteData.o SwanVTKPDataSets.o ocpids.o ocpcre.o ocpmix.o fftpack51.o" swan.exe
gfortran swmod1.f -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore  
gfortran swmod2.f -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore  
gfortran SwanSpectPart.f -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore  
gfortran m_constants.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran m_fileio.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran serv_xnl4v5.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran mod_xnl4v5.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran SwanGriddata.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran SwanGridobjects.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran SwanCompdata.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran SdsBabanin.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran SwanIEM.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran SwanBraggScat.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran SwanQCM.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran swan2coh.f90 -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore -ffree-line-length-none  
gfortran swanmain.f -c -O -w -fno-second-underscore  
swanmain.f:8947:22:

 7114 |       CALL SWBROADC ( BSPECS, 2*MDC*MSC*NBSPEC, SWREAL )                  40.30
      |                      2
......
 8947 |         CALL SWBROADC(IFLIDL(IGR1),1,SWINT)                               40.30
      |                      1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(4)/REAL(4)).
make[1]: *** [swanmain.o] Error 1
make: *** [ser] Error 2
```

Comment: I think it's unlikely to be related to the M1 vs M2 vs x86/64 chip except accidentally.  It looks as if there's a bug — a set of type mismatches between a function call and a function definition — in the code.

Comment: Yes, this is simply a bug in the code you are trying to compile which versions of GCC 10+ detect. You can try compiling with `-fallow-argument-mismatch` added to `FFLAGS90` or asking the developers to fix the code.